# .NET TreeView Change Expansion Symbol (+/- to > Symbol)

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

Is it possible to change .NET TreeView control from +/- symbols to > symbol, similar to regedit on Windows 10.

TreeView Default

[image]

Desired View

[image]

Is possible how can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes this method works fine at runtime, it breaks Windows form designer though, although in my case that is not a problem. Designer gets error The service System.Windows.Forms.Design.IEventHandlerService already exists in the service container. Parameter name: serviceType 
at System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer.AddService(Type serviceType, ServiceCreatorCallback callback, Boolean promote)

Comment: that issue was fixed by using "Clean Build", then rebuilding the project